# Is a loan lent with a rate under the inflation rate free money?

Tags: inflation, interest-rate

Suppose we have an inflation in a country with an annual 2% and we get a loan for an annual 1% (real interest). Is the money we receive free? 
This is a common practice in some European countries, where the mortgages are around 1% fix rate plus the Euro Interank Offered Rate.
If so, why? Are the banks loosing money by lending in such low rates?

Comment: Is the interest of $1\%$ real or nominal?

Comment: Please accept the answer if it was helpful

Comment: To be clear, we are talking about an interest rate = EURIBOR + 1%?

Answer (score -1):

You have the right intuition.

However, 1% is usually the real interest rate.

*Real interest rate = nominal interest rate - inflation*

So, you are actually, usually, paying a 3% annual rate.

If that is not the case, your question does not specify if 1% is nominal or real, then just having inflation of x% does not mean that you are increasing your wealth my that much each year.

Example: Inflation is 10%. The best investment opportunity provides a return of 0.5%. By the end of the year, I am still losing 9.5% of my wealth. But does that mean that I should not invest at all? If I don't then I will lose 10% which is wrose.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

"Real interest" means the interest after subtracting inflation. Interest including inflation would be called "nominal interest".

If inflation is 2%, then 1% real interest means 3% nominal interest, which is the interest that is written in the loan contract and is what you actually have to pay. You would have to pay \$300 interest on a \$10000 loan. However, if you put the \$10000 into a savings account that matched inflation, you would have \$10200 at the end of it. So you would have lost \$100 overall.

Answer (score -2):

Inflation: 2%
Interest:  1%

This means the real rate is 3%. 
So no; not free money.

Free money would be negative interest rates. 
Example: Inflation: 0%.
         Interest on loan I get from the bank: -1%.
This would mean they are paying ME 1% to take the loan from the bank.

Negative interest rates are a real practice, with many historical examples that can be researched.

The banks are theoretically losing 1%(+2% inflation) on the loaned amount, however it's important to understand that deals are made among negotiations with central banks in the background that can still produce gains from this.

Comment: You are taking his question in the wrong way. Please see my answer below.

Comment: You repeated my answer but said it differently.

Comment: Not really the same but I guess it works

Comment: If inflation is 2% and nominal interest is 1%, then the real interest rate is -1%.

Comment: Sorry but that is not correct, you do not subtract them, you add them for the real interest rate. If I take a loan out from the bank at a nominal interest rate of 1%, and inflation is 2%, then I'm effectively paying 3%. The bank's return on the loan however is -1%.

Comment: Effectively, everybody loses the 2%, but the bank then makes 1% back off you.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Acccumulation Yes but the question says 1% real interest which means 3% nominal interest.

Comment: @user253751 This answer says "Inflation: 2% Interest: 1%

This means the real rate is 3%." Saying that the real rate is 3% is wrong. (And technically, the rates are multiplied, not added).